# Can Info.plist file contain unused usage descriptions?

Tags: ios, plist, info.plist, apple-developer, ios-permissions

Can I enter usage descriptions for all available permissions in the Info.plist file and actually use only a few in the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I enter usage descriptions for all available permissions in the Info.plist file and actually use only a few in the application?

Of course you can. You can do whatever you like. But don't try get such an app thru the App Store; Apple doesn't like that. There needs to be a place in the app where the user *might* encounter every usage permission dialog you register, and you will have to tell Apple how to reach it.